# Merging two lists of elements into one with the same elements but two variables per element

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I have two lists of 48 elements. Each element in the list has one variable (DiffINT or DiffEXT below), with differing numbers of observations. The names of all of the elements are the same in both lists.

What I would like to do is merge the two lists of elements based on the element name and end up with two variables per element.

Bonus question: I have two lists of 48 elements, both lists have the same elements. One list has one variable with one observation in it, the other list as six variables per element with varied numbers of observations. Can I somehow merge these to accomplish the same as above?

I have reviewed other questions and tried append() and cbind() and other functions, but none of them accomplish what I want. Example of what I am looking for is below.

```
> str(DiffsMerged)
List of 48
 $ Element1:List of 2
  ..$ DiffINT : num 1 0.642 0.27 -0.102 -0.123 ...
  ..$ DiffEXT : num 1 0.1397 -0.1045 -0.0751 -0.1414 ...
 $ Element 2:List of 2
  ..$ DiffINT : num  1 0.5842 0.3453 0.158 -0.0259 ...
  ..$ DiffEXT : num 1 -0.0312 -0.0321 -0.033 -0.0339 ...
 $ Element 3:List of 2
  ..$ DiffINT : num 1 0.908 0.816 0.724 0.632 ...
  ..$ DiffEXT : num 1 0.584 0.21 -0.163 -0.406
```

Many thanks in advance.

Edit to add: Whenever I want to view the individual lists (DiffINT and DiffEXT), I get the following error. Thoughts?

```
 > View(DiffEXT)
 Error in if (more || nchar(output) > 80) { : 
   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: You can convert the lists to data frames and use join to get the output you need.

Comment: @krpa How do I go about that? Especially for lists that have multiple variables in each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a simple "merge" with a `lapply` loop:

```
all_names <- union(names(DiffINT), names(DiffEXT))
DiffsMerged <- lapply(
  X   = all_names,
  FUN = function(name) {
    list(DiffINT[[name]], DiffEXT[[name]])
  }
)
names(DiffsMerged) <- all_names
str(DiffsMerged)
# List of 3
#  $ Element1:List of 2
#   ..$ : num [1:5] 1 0.642 0.27 -0.102 -0.123
#   ..$ : num [1:5] 1 0.1397 -0.1045 -0.0751 -0.1414
#  $ Element2:List of 2
#   ..$ : num [1:5] 1 0.1397 -0.1045 -0.0751 -0.1414
#   ..$ : num [1:5] 1 -0.0312 -0.0321 -0.033 -0.0339
#  $ Element3:List of 2
#   ..$ : num [1:5] 1 0.908 0.816 0.724 0.632
#   ..$ : num [1:5] 1 0.584 0.21 -0.163 -0.406
```

I don't know what you plan to use this data for, but it could help to keep it [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html). Only do this if both lists have the same names, and all elements have the same length.

```
int_df <- data.frame(DiffINT)
int_df[["source"]] <- "int"
ext_df <- data.frame(DiffEXT)
ext_df[["source"]] <- "ext"
merged_df <- rbind(int_df, ext_df)
merged_df
#    Element1 Element2 Element3 source
# 1    1.0000   1.0000    1.000    int
# 2    0.6420   0.1397    0.908    int
# 3    0.2700  -0.1045    0.816    int
# 4   -0.1020  -0.0751    0.724    int
# 5   -0.1230  -0.1414    0.632    int
# 6    1.0000   1.0000    1.000    ext
# 7    0.1397  -0.0312    0.584    ext
# 8   -0.1045  -0.0321    0.210    ext
# 9   -0.0751  -0.0330   -0.163    ext
# 10  -0.1414  -0.0339   -0.406    ext
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed! Thank you! The tidy bit helps too, although I am not yet ready to use it with my data. Thanks again.